# free up on malloc fails

Tags: c

I have some thing like this

```
char *temp, xyz;
temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(somestring));

xyz = (char *) malloc(sizeof(temp));
xyz= strrchar(temp, "_"); // temp does not contain "_", but need to check for error validation
```

Now If I try to do 
    free(temp);
its crashing;

any idea, I am a beginer.

Comment: You're sure it's crashing on free()? How do you fill temp?

Comment: With proper compiler settings this shouldn't compile (there's a reason to use them!)

Comment: temp was assigned with strcpy call
     strcpy(temp, something);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, correct me if I am wrong,
xyz is just pointing to the location where it has the "_" in the string temp. As soon as I free up the temp, that location got freed up. but xyz is still pointing to that location, which is already freed. That is the reason I had crash on freeing xyz.

Comment: yes that would lead to problems. When you use `strchr` you only need a `char *` pointer to reference parts of the string, by pointing to memoru _inside_ the already-allocated string. This pointer, `xyz` in your case, **doesn't** need to have memory allocated for it, and doesn't need to be free'd. You'll free the original string - **only** if it's dynamically allocated with `malloc` - at some later point, assuming that you correctly kept a reference to it.

Answer (score 14):

The first problem is that `xyz` is **not** being declared as a `char *`, only a single `char`.

Given the following variable declaration:

```
char *temp, xyz;
```

- `temp` is a pointer to a `char`.
- `xyz` is only a `char`.

The `*` **doesn't** apply to both variables. To make both variables pointers to `char`, use:

```
char *temp, *xyz;
```

Next: you're confusing the usage of `sizeof` with `strlen`. `sizeof` gives you the size occupied by a type or a variable of that type. So if `temp` is a `char *`, then `sizeof(temp)` will be the size of a pointer, **not** the length of a C string. To get C string lengths - e.g. to get the buffer size that you'll need to copy a given C string - use [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).

Finally, unless you've omitted some significant code there's another problem: simply using `malloc` doesn't do anything with the newly allocated memory, so after:

```
temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(somestring));
```

`temp` points to an uninitialized bit of memory (which is, as mentioned, probably smaller than you think it is due to using `sizeof` rather than `strlen`). Then you go on to *use* `temp` as if it's a valid C string, with `strchr`. This will likely access memory that doesn't belong to you, which invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Actually xyz is of type char *, that was a typo (my bad). I have changes sizeoff to strlen in place now. but still I have the same problem, BTW after malloc I do have strcpy(temp, something); If I do debugging on this "temp" has the string I am expecting.     
Now the code block looks like below
    char *temp, *xyz;
    temp = (char *)malloc(strlen(somestring));
    strcpy(temp, something); // value in something is copied to temp
    xyz = (char *) malloc(strlen(temp));
    xyz= strrchar(temp, "_"); // temp does not contain "_", but need to check for error validation

Comment: if(temp !=NULL) free(temp);
    if(something != NULL) free(something);
this is what I have at the end, where I am seeing th crash